# Clean a string so that it is valid for a certain regular expression

Tags: php, regex, validation

I've a set of rules to validate certain inputs. I am using regular expressions to test whether the input is valid or not. Here is my code. I've approx 20 rules, but showing only 2 here.

```
$rules    = array( 'telnum' => '/^[0-9,+]+$/i', 'firstname'=>'/^[a-z\'-]+$/i');
```

Say I want to validate a phone number.

```
$match = ((bool)preg_match($rules['telnum'], $str));
```

It is works fine. Now in certain cases, I need to parse some information and clean it so they are valid according to these rules. I've come to know that preg_replace is to be used. Can I use the same rules to clean the string or certain changes to rules are required? as

```
$cleanstr = preg_replace($rules['telnum'] , '', '+1 (214) 662-2590');
```

is not working for me. It should return +12146622590, but it returns the same string '+1 (214) 662-2590'.

EDIT -- Please note that the code will not detect which rule applies to the string. I'll specifically tell the rule to be used for each string. As I know whether a string is a phone number or firstname.

Comment: `'/^[^0-9\,\+]+$/'` ?

Comment: You cannot use your validation patterns for cleaning. .

Comment: @HAL9000 .. Thanks.. So this means that I just need to add a ^ in the regular expression? (I've about 20 rules, so will this apply to all rules?)

Comment: @HAL9000, This is not working for me.

Comment: @sectus .. Yes .. this is what I've learnt till now :) but there should be a way to convert the validation patterns to cleaning patterns.

Comment: No there shouldn't. How is the interpreter supposed to know how a given input should be transformed into a valid string? Let's say there's not a single digit in there, what then? Or if you just pass a date. It *could* be converted to a string that matches the expression but "20140120" wouldn't make sense as a phone number at all.

Comment: Just a slight change to HAL9000 solution worked. I just removed the ending $ and initial ^. It is like     '/[^0-9\,\+]+/'    . It is working for me.

Comment: @Khan, you have very strange validation pattern for phone number.

Comment: For very simple patterns this negation may work, for more complex cases it's not possible.

Comment: @sectus: :) I just need to allow numbers, and a + for international numbers and allow user to separate multiple numbers with comma.

Comment: @deceze There are nothing complex, just simple rules like you have seen above.

Comment: @hanzi there is no chance that a date will be passed. I dont need to check that either. The string passed will be a phone number for sure. This cleaning is just to make sure that same pattern is used for all phone numbers; Nothing complex.

Comment: @Khan, your pattern allow one number or comma or plus. Or '+++++++++++++++++++', or ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,', or '1+1+1+1+1+1'. But it's not a phone number.

Comment: So I am just going to replace '/^[0-9,+]+$/i' with '/[^0-9,+]+/i'. preg_replace('/[^0-9,+]+/i' , '', $phoneno) is working for me. Mods! Should I post this as answer?

Comment: @Khan, you could do it, feel free. But know that your patterns checks a little bit more than nothing.

Comment: @sectus you are right.. but the business logic require only soft validation (i.e. no extra character is acceptable, and then leave it to user to give a valid number). I don't know whether I can have an expression that can validate phone number for All countries in the world!

Answer (score 0):

There is one way. You could erase sybmols from input string and check with your pattern for every combination. So you must generate all combinations of erased sybmols from input string. It would be *131072* combinations for *'+1 (214) 662-2590'* string.

For example.

```
$string = '+1 (214) 662-2590';
$pattern = '/^[0-9,+]+$/i';

$strlen = strlen($string);
$iterations = pow(2, $strlen);

for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++)
    {
    $tmp_string = $string;
    $number = $i;
    $k = 1;
    while ($number)
        {
        if ($number % 2)
            $tmp_string = substr_replace($tmp_string, '', $strlen - $k, 1);
        $number = (int) ($number / 2);
        $k++;
        }

        if (preg_match($pattern, $tmp_string))
            {
            var_dump($tmp_string); // string(12) "+12146622590" 
            break;
            }
        }
```

With this you could use your validation expressions without editing its :^ )

Comment: I don't know whether you have understood my question right. All I need to do is to get a cleaned string .i.e. if    $str = '+1 (214) 662-2590', then output should be    $cleanstr = '+12146622590' which validates as per regular expression '/^[0-9,+]+$/i'.